# Accessing cordova.js from remote website

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, remote-server

I want to use the phonegap / cordova API within the InAppBrowser on Android, but it doenst work for me. I search for many days to solve the Problem, but i dont find the solution.

Thats the way i include the js files on the remote server:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.domain.com/js/cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.domain.com/js/cordova_plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.domain.com/js/inappbrowser.js"></script>
```

Is there a problem that my website uses SSL with the https protocol?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady()
        {
            win = window.open('https://www.domain.com/?is_app=1','_blank', 'location=no');
        }

    </script>
```

Worst case: Is there an alternative to cordova / phonegap that will do the job without that problems and works with geolocation etc.?

Comment: Here some notes, what i plan to do: geolocation, push-messages, login-routine (localstorage will to it, i think)

Comment: are your only using cordova for geo location? as cordova is meant to run locally for devices mainly as packaged store apps not from a remote webserver

Comment: No, i will use an entire responsive website that load within the app. On that website i will intetrage a geo-tracking tool.

Comment: u don;t need cordova for responsiveness for or for location, thought of using HTML5 works across all major browsers inc mobile ? can link you a sample if needed

Comment: sure. please send me your link.

Comment: here u go accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487929/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentpositon-isnt-working-on-chrome-and-firefox/22488058#22488058

Comment: wow that works...! Thanks. Can you tell how i can update the coords? I mean, the current lat / lng are great, but i need to update the values for tracking. Did u know if that works on IOS too?

Comment: And i want to track in the background. That doesnt work yet, have u a solution for that too?

Comment: im not sure what ur asking me friend, pls elaborate, i have not tested IOS but it should work as IOS support the the HTML location API

Comment: Sorry, here in detail: I want to track the locations in the background, even if the smartphone islocked (but still on). I try'd but it doesnt call the js script (ajax) that send me the current location. Hope that help

Comment: Once the app is in the background no javascript will ever run. however the code runs in the background it's asynch, this is down to device manufacturers not allowing it, cant say they ever will

Comment: But, how do the other cordova apps use the API? I meen, many cordova apps use the remote-website way and can use geolocation etc. How looks the best way to use an remote website and the cordova api?